# How to assign hotkey to certain command in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, development-environment, hotkeys

I would like to assign hotkeys to certain TFS client commands in visual studio.

For instance, hotkey1 for checkin, hotkey2 for undo checkout.

Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard

Then you can search for an action and set a hotkey for this action.

Using Tools > Import and export settings you can even save them to import them back on another machine.

As pointed out by richard, the actions you are looking for are File.TfsCheckin and File.TfsCheckout.

Comment: If you type into the text box near the top it will filter the list of commands. I think the Q needs `File.TfsCheckin` and `File.TfsCheckout`

Comment: Ok, thanks, actually what I was going to ask - what action in this list is TFS checkin and TFS undo checkout. I just can't find it.